# Why can't e-mail be relayed without an SMTP server?

Tags: email, smtp

I am thinking of setting up an SMTP server, but only so that it can relay any email sent to it to some actual email services (gmail, yahoo).

I am having some trouble doing that, but it got me thinking, why exactly do I need an SMTP server to do that? If its only task is to forward any message sent to it to another server, why exactly can't the client computer do the exact same thing it does?

I searched the web and everyone seems to agree that you need an SMTP server to send email, but why is that, why the need for such a middleman?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. Either you want to relay the mail, then you need _something_ to relay that, and that's what smtp relays/servers do. Or you don't.

Comment: I just mean sending the email to whichever server is responsible for a particular destination email address.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between MUA, MSA, MTA and MDA? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_agent_(infrastructure)

Answer (score 1):

You need an SMTP server which is willing to relay your email. This is because of the email spam.

Need of the SMTP server is depending of the address on the sender.

You can send messages via gmail or yahoo if you have your account, using that email as sender address, but having your own domain like whatever.com is a different story.